# Grabbing the class on an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, prototypejs

I am able to grab the id from an iframe with this

```
var iFrame = window.top.document.getElementById('window_<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>_content');
```

however I can not figure out how to grab the class of that iframe. The prototype library is loaded on the site as well but I do not know how to make the $ selector grab something from window.top

The reason I have to do this is because the id is generated in two different ways from the site and will not work for my purposes.

I started playing around with

```
var iFrame = window.top.document.getElementsByClassName('theIframe');
```

but it is not working for me yet...

Any ideas on how I can grab the class name of the iFrame?  How can I reach to top with prototype selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the class:

```
window.top.document.getElementById('window_<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>_content').className
```

If you are storing the iframe element in a variable anyway, you can use:

```
iFrame.className
```

Comment: Ahh.. thanks, that would totally work... but I left out a very important part of the question. window_content actually has a dynamically generated integer as part of it as well.  I updated my question.

Comment: I will accept because you are right and I did a crappy job of asking my question so using ->getID is not an option for me.  I realized I could grab the name which is the same as the ID and pass that instead.  Thanks for your help.